# How to increment String Name using Scanner, while and a for loop in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, java-8, java.util.scanner

I am trying to auto assign a  Unique  string name "a-n" to `scan.next()` using Scanner. How can I use `for i` loop to auto assign the names instead of manually listing the name of the string.  For Example:

```
String s = ("Hello there how are you?");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(s);
while (scan.hasNext()) {
           String a-1 = scan.next();
           String a-2 = scan.next();
           String a-3 = scan.next();
         }
```

so when I do

```
System.out.println(a-1); Prints --> Hello
System.out.println(a-2); Prints --> there
System.out.println(a-3); Prints --> how
```

Now, assuming that I am reading from a file instead of a string and I don't know how long the string is, how can I populate the string names with "a-n++" using a `for i` loop without knowing how long the string is?

I want to be able to auto generate the following:

```
String a-1 = scan.next();
String a-2 = scan.next();
String a-3 = scan.next(); 
String a-n = scan.next();
```

where `n++` as long as the string has `scan.next()`

Comment: You can't. You can use an array, List, or Map.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. you are correct. Map is what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into Map (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), which is also known as a dictionary or associative array. You can assign a value, in this case the word read from Scanner, to a key.

Comment: It would have been nice if your comment included a working example, but thanks for the pointer and I marked your answer as the correct one.